# How to access every object of array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ionic2

I am facing a problem in accessing array of every object please take a look at my response structure.

```
 {
      "status": "1",
      "status_text": "Success",
      "current_page": 1,
      "next_page": "0",
      "previous_page": "0",
      "total_page": 1,
      "total_products": "5",
      "data": {
        "products": [
          {
            "product_id": "51",
            "name": "Arm Rocker",
            "description": "",
            "meta_title": "arm rocker",
            "meta_description": "",
            "model": "AutoSpare",
            "image": "http://192.168.1.6/opencart/image/catalog/demo/product/armRocker-200x200.jpg",
            "options": [
              {
                "product_option_value_id": "45",
                "name": "Bangalore Auto",
                "quantity": "12",
                "sku": "56876",
                "price": "100.00",
                "salesprice": "50"
              },
              {
                "product_option_value_id": "51",
                "name": "Hyderabad Auto",
                "quantity": "23",
                "sku": "56543",
                "price": "200.00",
                "salesprice": "60"
              },
              {
                "product_option_value_id": "52",
                "name": "Delhi Auto",
                "quantity": "14",
                "sku": "98767",
                "price": "300.00",
                "salesprice": "80"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "product_id": "57",
            "name": "Avenger",
            "description": "<p>Hi, This is for testing....</p>",
            "meta_title": "avenger",
            "meta_description": "",
            "model": "AutoSpare",
            "image": "http://192.168.1.6/opencart/image/catalog/demo/product/avengerDtsi-150x150.jpg",
            "options": [
              {
                "product_option_value_id": "48",
                "name": "Bangalore Auto",
                "quantity": "68",
                "sku": "978675",
                "price": "200.00",
                "salesprice": "150"
              },
              {
                "product_option_value_id": "49",
                "name": "Delhi Auto",
                "quantity": "67",
                "sku": "86757",
                "price": "300.00",
                "salesprice": "250"
              },
              {
                "product_option_value_id": "50",
                "name": "Hyderabad Auto",
                "quantity": "54",
                "sku": "98765",
                "price": "400.00",
                "salesprice": "350"
              }
            ]
          }
]
    }
```

in the above json structure i have an **data** object in that i have an array of **products** i have two objects in that array

> here catprodArray is the **products** array

each and every object has **options** array what i am trying to achive in html part is given below.

```
<div class="product" *ngFor="let category of catprodArray">
   <div>{{category.image}}</div>
   <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>price</ion-label>
                        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="price">
                          <ion-option value="f" *ngFor="let item of category.option[]">{{item.sku}}</ion-option>

                        </ion-select>
                    </ion-item>
</div>
```

> in my **ion-select** opttions i am trying to access that **options** array but i am getting error like

```
    browser_adapter.js:84 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ] at column 35 in [ngFor let item of category.option[]] in CategoryProductDetailsPage@105:33 ("-label>price</ion-label>
                        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="price">
                          <ion-option value="f" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of category.option[]">{{item.sku}}</ion-option>

                        </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-option value="f" *ngFor="let item in category.product_id.option[]">{{item.sku}}</ion-option>
```

should be like this

```
<ion-option value="f" *ngFor="let item of category.product_id.option[]">{{item.sku}}</ion-option>
```

## Update Try this-

```
<ion-option value="f" *ngFor="let item of category?.options">{{item.sku}}</ion-option>
```

we use `?` (Elvis Operator) at the end of variable while fetching asynchronous data which is coming from some kind of web API or JSON
by using this angular2 will prevent us from throwing any error when data is not available for view
READ more here

- http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0

Comment: sorry my mistake i have actually given `of` only on there but still getting error i have tried in both ways like `category.product_id.option[]` and also like this `category.option[]` but i am getting error on that line

Comment: can you give some explaination for this `category.product_id?.options` why you use ? over the end of the product_id?

Comment: but i am not able to see my options of sku value on clicking the options filed

Comment: where you have provided the click event  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123334/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-pardeep-jain).